# expensive api call in server component for nextjs13

Tags: reactjs, next.js

i have this server component

```
const ContentSubmissions = async () => {
  const blogsData: any = await getBlogsData();
  const galleryData: any = await getGalleryData();
  const questionsData: any = await getQuestionsData();

  const fullData = [ 
    ...blogsData,
    ...galleryData,
    ...questionsData,
  ];

  return (
    <p className="text-lg md:text-2xl font-bold text-white">
      {fullData ? fullData.length : 0}
    </p>
  );
};
```

which is used like

```
        <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
          <ContentSubmissions />
        </Suspense>
```

in a client component.

the problem is that it is an expensive call, and each time user re-visit the page it re-fetch all of the data,

is there a way to deal with it? like caching? limiting calls? or whats the best way to avoid  multiple calls

function like getBlogsData is a get docs from collection in fire base :

```
export async function getBlogsData() {
  const blogsData: any[] = [];
  const blogRef = query(collection(db, "blogs"));

  const snapshot = await getDocs(blogRef);
  if (snapshot.empty) {
    console.log("No matching documents.");
    return [];
  }
  snapshot.forEach((doc: any) => {
    blogsData.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() });
  });
  return blogsData;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have many options to do so. You can use revalidateTag, whenever blogs, questions, or gallery gets changed, updated, or deleted, you revalidate the tag that's associated with that fetch.

Example:

```
fetch('.../id/123', {
  next: {
    revalidate: 3600 * 2,
    tags:['blog:id:123']
  },
});

// when the blog is updated
const db.updateBlogId("123")
revalidateTag('blog:id:123')
```

Read more here: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating

You can also optimize the speed of your three independent api calls by doing a Promise.all([...])

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i dont see how to use fetch() in my case,

Comment: put your db execution in a /api route. otherwise u may have to use revalidatePath